# 1 in 192 quadrillion outcome?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to work out the likelihood of attaining specific results from a specific number of assessments:

There is possibility of attaining A, B, C and D and 3 assessments are undertaken by 10 people. what is the likelihood that 9 people would attain AAA and the other person would attain an ABC?

I worked out there are 64 outcomes by $4^3$, and manually made a table to verify that this 64 was correct.

I then worked out outcomes by $(\frac{n! assessments}{{n! grade . n! grade . n! grade}})$:

AAA: $\frac{3!}{3!}$ = 1

and, 1A 1B 1C: $\frac{3!}{1!.1!.1!}$ = 6

I then surmise that attaining AAA is $\frac{1}{64}$ and ABC is $\frac{6}{64}$.

To then work out the likelihood of 9 people attaining AAA and 1 attaining 1A 1B 1C when 10 people undertook the assessments:

$(\frac{6}{64}).(\frac{1}{64})^9$

= [$(\frac{3}{{576460752303423488}})$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%286%2F64%29%281%2F64%29%5E%7B9%7D)

= $\frac{3}{{576460752303423488}}$ = $\frac{1}{{x}}$

$x$ = $\frac{576460752303423488}{{3}}$

The likelihood that 9 out of 10 people attain AAA and remaining person attains ABC when undertook 3 assessments and 4 grades:

= 1 in [$1.921535841011411626... ×10^{17}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=576460752303423488%2F3)

= 192 quadrillion.

This seems insanely high to me so I am unsure if I'm going about this in the wrong way.

I've rationalised it to myself by thinking of it as a national exam:

Out of 10,000 people doing national exam: 9,000 people getting AAA, 1000 people getting 1A 1B and 1C and no other grades attained whatsoever is of course an incredibly unrealistic outcome.

But, is it really 1 in 192,000,000,000,000,000 - or am I missing something from the calculation?

Comment: I haven't finished reading your post, but even in the first paragraph or two you lost me.  There are possibilities of getting A's, B's, C's, and D's...  Sure... *However* you have not told us anything at all about how frequently each of these occur.  Is getting an A just as likely to happen as getting a B or C or D?  Does an occurrence of an A impact at all what other people might get?  If you give an easy test to the smartest people, they might all get perfect scores and all get A's.  If you have four people compete in a race, exactly one of them will come in first, etc...

Comment: Next... don't call things *permutations* which are not in fact permutations.  "*I worked out there are 64 permutations by $4^3$*"  You are describing *arrangements* or *outcomes* or *sequences* or some other word like this which is sufficiently general.  **Permutations** on the other hand very explicitly must contain each outcome **exactly** once each.  Using the word "permutations" to describe general arrangements is a bastardization of the term which I will not stand for.

Comment: You should multiply your final fraction by 10, to account for the fact that any one of the 10 people could have gotten the ABC.

Comment: The probability that everyone gets AAA, assuming A/B/C/D are all equally likely, is clearly $4^{-30}$ which is about 1 in $1.15\times10^{18}$. So this slightly different outcome is slightly more probable; that seems reasonable. (But again, this is incredibly dependent on the assumption that A/B/C/D are all equally likely.)

Comment: "*This seems insanely high to me*"  Your calculations are (*almost*) correct (*after accounting for the factor of 10 mentioned by GregMartin*) for the most common assumptions for the problem (*uniformity and independence*) and it really does get that incredibly improbable that quickly.  Surely, you've played with dice before... perhaps played the game of Yahtzee.  You've seen how infrequently you actually get a yahtzee on a single throw.  Now, imagine getting a yahtzee on the first throw *five times in a row.*  That's effectively what you're doing here.

Comment: Also, regarding "Out of 10,000 people doing national exam: 9,000 people getting AAA, 1000 people getting 1A 1B and 1C and no other grades attained whatsoever is of course an incredibly unrealistic outcome." That is not a good comparison at all: multiplying the number of people by 1000 will roughly raise the odds to the 1000th power. That's like saying getting two heads in a row flipping a fair coin is about the same as getting 2000 heads in a row.

Comment: Thank you @JMoravitz and please accept my apologies on terminology. I do not know how frequently each occurs - which is why I simply the individual outcomes. I believe that it is as likely to achieve an A as a B or C or D, but I don't know how to justify that assumption. I appreciate the analogy of the race - each occurrence is independent of one another so will not impact other occurrences.

Comment: Thank you @GregMartin. I don't follow "multiply your final fraction by 10, to account for the fact that any one of the 10 people could have gotten the ABC" - You mean the (1/64)^9 should be (1/64)^10? I did ^9 because it represents 9 out of 10 and it is being multipled by the other 1 out of 10. Or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: Please also excuse me, @GregMartin, but why is everyone getting AAA clearly 4^-30?

Comment: @GeorgeLamb If there is a $1/4$th chance of getting A then the chance of getting x3 A is $1/4^3$ and the chance that all ten get it is $(1/4^3)^{10} = 1/4^{30} = 4^{-30}$.  Also why "multiply your final fraction by 10" is because the first person could get ABC or the second person could get ABC or the third person, etc.  Just reply if you have any further questions. :)